# How to implement these two boundary conditions in 1D differential discretization scheme?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\begin{cases}
\left.\dfrac{\partial^3 h}{\partial x^3}\right|_{x=0} & =0\\[8pt]
\left.\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0} &=0
\end{cases}$$

Nodes $x$ are from $0$ to $N$. The value on the boundary ($h_{x=0}$) is required.

Use $h_{-1}$ as a ghost point for differential discretization of third derivative.

For first-order derivative,

$$\left.\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}=\frac{h_1-h_{-1}}{2\,\Delta x}=0，$$

so the value of ghost point is 
$$h_{-1}=h_1$$

For third-order derivative,

$$\left.\frac{\partial^3 h}{\partial x^3}\right|_{x=0}=\frac{h_2-3h_1+3h_0-h_{-1}}{(\Delta x)^3}=0$$

Then $h_0=\dfrac{4h_1-h_2}{3}$, since $h_{-1}=h_1$

Is above implementation correct? or please give me a better scheme. Thanks